# Is F# available for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012

I just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 express for Desktop but cannot launch an F# project. I see no where online where I can install it for Visual Studio 2012 express for Desktop. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually available for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. You need to download the F# Tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web (blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-f-tools-for-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web.aspx , download link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=FSharpVWD11). I do not think it is available for the Desktop version of Visual Studio Express 2012.

Comment: It seems this has possibly changed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/01/22/announcing-visual-f-3-1-1-and-support-for-desktop-express.aspx

Answer (score 4):

While it is only available for the web version of Visual Studio Express, there is nothing stopping you from writing desktop applications with it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4R9EfFNgLU